# Does Deathtrap get my Shock Damage boosts?

Tags: borderlands-2

Thanks to Make It Sparkle I can turn Deathtrap's melee attacks into Shock elemental. Does he get my shock damage boost from Wires Don't Talk? Further, does he also get shock damage boosts from other sources like elemental relics?

Answer (score 1):

[The folks over at Wikia speculate that Wires Don't Talk? does add to Make It Sparkle](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Wires_Don%27t_Talk).

> If you set Deathtrap's element to Electrical through the use of Make
>   it Sparkle, then Wires Don't Talk may also increase his damage.

However looking at the actual skill description for Wires Don't Talk.

> Increases all Shock and Electrocute Damage that you inflict.
>   Shock and Electrocute Damage: +3% per skill rank.

It mentions **you** specifically, so that you lead me to surmise that it won't apply to anything else.

There doesn't seem to be much chatter on the Gearbox forums about these skills.

Comment: I just need to test it manually, from casual observation it does'nt seem to though (Fire deathtrap still deals more elemental damage to flesh targets than Shock, but with all of my shock boosts they should be equal)